# Trying to Fix Intermittent Video Freezes

Tags: video, freeze, intel

### Problem Description:

At seemingly random points, the video and audio from what I was watching will hang, and the program will usually stop responding to my input.  I typically end up closing the offending program after waiting to make sure it isn't buffering or something like that.

### Observational Information:

- This has happened in both mpv and VLC, with similar behavior in each (loss of input control)
- I am positive my problem is specific to video files only.  I was able to play multiple music files using mpv without the freezing occuring.  However, the audio of the video that suddenly stopped would likewise stop.
- I have launched both mpv and VLC from the command line with varying verbosity levels to see if STDOUT/STDERR had any useful information, to no avail.
- Using mpv with default settings (no hardware decoding enabled), I was unable to reproduce the problem.

My current hypothesis is that it has something to do with the hardware video decoding, but I'm not really sure what to test or where to go from here.  I've tried searching on Google, but video freezing seems to be a general enough problem that I couldn't find anything that sounded like what is happening to me.

Is there anything else I can try?  Or is there a way I can diagnose if my laptop's video hardware decoding is malfunctioning?

### Software Information:

- I am using Arch Linux
- I have all the necessary packages for Intel video hardware decoding ([libva-intel-driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VA-API) 1.4.1-1)
- The ArchWiki page on [Intel Graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics) contained a [subsection pertaining to freezing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#X_freeze.2Fcrash_with_intel_driver), but it looks like that is for problems with X in general.  I tried it without success.
- Here is my `vainfo` output:

  ```
  libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
  libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
  libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
  libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_36
  libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
  vainfo: VA-API version: 0.36 (libva 1.4.1)
  vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile - 1.4.1
  vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
        VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
        VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
  ```

Answer (score 0):

ironlake (don't know about sandy bridge) was affected by improper handling in mesa, this issue seems to be fixed in newer versions (it was fixed in august 2015)

see https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91254